# Replace &amp; with & with retaining string length in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am looking for a solution to a problem:

I have a fixed length string which looks like:

```
 99               9999999999999                               999999ZK9999.999999999999.999999999 (9999999)                       Text &amp; to change                    something random here
```

I want to replace any `&amp;` symbol with `&`, but only when this symbol is located between 130, and 170 characters from the left.
I want also add necessary spaces at the end of the substring, so the length stays the same:

```
 99               9999999999999                               999999ZK9999.999999999999.999999999 (9999999)                       Text & to change                        something random here
```

There maybe more than one `&amp;` to replace.

At the moment I'm creating 3 substrings, then I make all the necessary changes in the 2nd, and I'm connecting substrings back together.

```
            my $subline1 = substr $line, 0, 130;
            my $subline2 = substr $line, 130, 40;
            my $subline3 = substr $line, 170;
            if ($subline2 =~ s/(&amp;)/&/ig) {
                while (length($subline2)<40){
                    $subline2=$subline2." ";
                }
                $line=$subline1.$subline2.$subline3;
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

EDIT: added my current solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `substr` call as an *lvalue*, so you could write something like this

Note that `s///g` returns the number of substitutions that it has made

I've used the `for` as a *topicaliser* to make the substring accessible as a simple variable `$_`

```
for ( substr $s, 130, 40 ) {
    my $n = s/&amp;/&/g;
    $_ .= ' ' x ( 4 * $n );
}
```

Comment: N.B. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html "Prior to Perl version 5.10, the result of using an lvalue multiple times was unspecified."

Comment: @ysth, Unspecified? Does that mean undocumented? If so, who cares?

Comment: @ikegami it means undocumented and not what anybody would want.  IIRC it would reuse the same starting length for the substring even if the length changed, so changing a length 4 substring to something with a length of 3 twice would end up removing a character from what was supposed to be outside the substring

Comment: @ysth, ug. So the important thing isn't that it was *unspecified*, but that it was *different*. *Oddly different*, even. They should have said "undefined behaviour" instead of "unspecifed result"!

Answer (score 0):

```
use HTML::Entities qw( decode_entities );

substr($s, 130, 40, sprintf('%-40s', decode_entities(substr($s, 130, 40))));
```

or

```
use HTML::Entities qw( decode_entities );

my $format = 'A130 A40 A*';
my @fields = unpack($format, $s);
$fields[1] = decode_entities($fields[1]);
$s = pack($format, @fields);
```